# reading byte array backwords in java

Tags: java, android, arrays

I have a byte array of very large size . I want to read it backward till I find a string like **BEGIN:VCARD** OR **END:VCARD** etc. I want to access the array line by line if possible.

Comment: I have not tried anything yet :) I was just thinking about the solution . Reading character by character would be difficult I thought. Any other solution ?

Comment: Byte arrays aren't strings. If you're looking for strings, and talking about reading by *lines*, you'll need to convert this into text data. How large is this "very large" byte array anyway?

Comment: @Jon Ya. I will convert it to String while checking for the particular string.

Comment: @rohit: Okay, so you don't actually need to know the answer for a byte array... you've got a string, so use String.lastIndexOf.

Comment: @Jon I will be getting a byte array itself. But its contents are that of a vcard(so basically they are string only).

Answer (score 3):

It should be a simple coding problem, using [`String.lastIndexOf(String str, int fromIndex)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf%28java.lang.String,%20int%29).  The rest is up to you.

---

If the byte array is so large that turning it onto a single string is will use too much memory, then scan backwards through the array to find the line boundaries, create a String for each line, and use `lastIndexOf` on each line string.

Comment: Please resist the temptation to code this for the OP.  He obviously needs the experience of doing it himself.

Answer (score 2):

If performance is not that important, you could first build a string via the byte-array constructor (new String(byte[] bytes)) and then String.lastIndexOf(String str) is your friend. It will give you the position of the **last** occurence of the given string.

Comment: the byte array is somewhat big in size . so I am trying to avoid this